# "Read-only" public properties without setters/getters

Tags: c#, oop, properties, readonly

Does C# have such a feature (like Python's getter-only pattern)?

```
class A 
{
   public [read-only] Int32 A_;

   public A() 
   {
      this.A_ = new Int32();
   }

   public A method1(Int32 param1) 
   {
      this.A_ = param1;
      return this;
   }
}

class B 
{
   public B() 
   {
      A inst = new A().method1(123);
      Int32 number = A.A_; // okay
      A.A_ = 456;          // should throw a compiler exception
   }
}
```

To obtain this I could use the private modifier on the A_ property, and only implement a getter method. Doing so, in order to access that property I should always make a call to the getter method... is it avoidable?

Comment: Yes. You can define properties with either one or both of `get` and `set`, with a backing field. However, this does not stop you from being able to get at the backing field inside the class. This has been expanded to auto-properties as of C# 6, auto-properties in C# 5 backwards have always had the ability to change the accessibility of either the getter or setter, but not the ability to omit one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible, syntax is like this:

```
public int AProperty { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

yes. you can use read only property with private setter.

[Using Properties - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

```
    public string Name    
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```